# Falha ao executar ionic server

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-cordova, ionic2, angular

Boa tarde,

estou tentando executar o ionic serve logo apos criar o projeto sem nem mexer em nada e sempre vem a mesma falha. Já não sei mais o que tentar.

Quando executo o comando "ionic serve" ele me traz essa mensagem, não rodando a aplicação.

```
ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
```

Essa falha persiste e não consigo executar. Estou rodando o node 6.10 cordova 6.5 e o ionic v2.

O que pode ser isso?

Comment: e qual exatamente é a falha?

Comment: ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"

Comment: Não aparece outra coisa... e não consigo acessar o app

Comment: acabei de perceber, nao seria somente `ionic serve` ?? No ionic v1 e  na [documentacao do v2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/serve/) esta somente  asssim.

Comment: Cara desculpa, escrevi errado aqui na pergunta. É sim ionic serve. E utilizando ele que da o erro

Comment: ok, mas tentou somente `ionic serve`? Por que alem de os parametros estarem formatados errados, esses sao os valores padrao, mas acho que o problema sao os parametros errados.

Comment: Tentei forçar com alguns parâmetros, tipo "ionic serve --lab" ou "ionic serve --127.0.0.1", mas mesmo assim ele ainda continua apresentando esse mesmo problema

Comment: Será que tem algo que ser alterado nas confs dos app?

Comment: Estou realizando um teste. Estou realizando o mesmo procedimento no windows para ver o problema também ira acontecer ou não. O problema aconteceu no Debian 8 64.

Comment: novamente a sintaxe do comando esta errada, o certo seria `ionic serve --address 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você acabou de criar o projeto, provavelmente ele baixou o ionic-app-scripts da versão 1.2.2, essa versão está apresentando esse problema em muitos sistemas, recomendo que faça o rollback da versão para a 1.1.4 que está funcionando corretamente usando o comando: `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@1.1.4 --save-dev`

Segue o issue no GitHub sobre o problema [1.2.2 "ionic serve" just hangs and not responding #858](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/858)